# Exception in when initializing gapi from google plus mobile chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile, google-plus, google-authentication

In my application I use google auth, I load some google libraries for this.
When I share my application in google plus and then go to google plus app on my mobile (android) and open it I get an exception when initializing google auth.
This happens only when opening my application from google plus app share link.

I debugged google plus chrome from my desktop and here is what I found:

There is an exception when trying to initialize auth2:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _.RE is not a function
pZ                                              @ cb=gapi.loaded_1:formatted:1705
jF                                              @ cb=gapi.loaded_1:formatted:1481
_.hN                                            @ cb=gapi.loaded_1:formatted:1770
(anonymous function)                            @ google.js:200
(anonymous function)                            @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
Ea                                              @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:4
b                                               @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
F.(anonymous function).F.(anonymous function)   @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
c                                               @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
(anonymous function)                            @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
Ea                                              @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:4
b                                               @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
F.(anonymous function).F.(anonymous function)   @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
c                                               @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
(anonymous function)                            @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
Ea                                              @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:4
b                                               @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
F.(anonymous function)                          @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
C.(anonymous function)                          @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
(anonymous function)                            @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:1
```

Here is my code for initializing gapi and auth:

```
if (!window.gapi) {
        $.getScript('//apis.google.com/js/platform.js', function () {
            $.getScript('//apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js', function () {
                gapi.load('auth2', function(){
                    gapi.auth2.init({
                        client_id: 'my-client-id',
                        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
                        scope: 'profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read'
                      }).then(function(){
                          auth2 = arguments[0];
                        authPromise.resolve();
                      },
                      function(){
                        authPromise.reject();
                      });
                });

                gapi.load('client', function() { 
                    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1').then(function() {
                        clientPromise.resolve();
                    }, function(){
                        clientPromise.reject();
                    });
                }, function(){
                    clientPromise.reject();
                });

            });
        });
```

The difference I found between my app when opening from chrome or when opening from google plus app are the files that are loaded:

- working version:
  [image]
- Not working version:
  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem:

When initializing google.auth2 I passed **cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin'**, removing this fixed the problem.